# How to edit repeated records in R?

Tags: r

My data has repeated questions. **I want to rename those repeated questions with 1, 2, 3, etc. depending on how many times they are asked/repeated**. eg: Were you given any info?, Were you given any info?2, Were you given any info?3

```
data:

    df1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                 Full.Name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe"), 
                 DOB = c("1-1-90", "1-1-90", "1-1-90", "2-2-80", "2-2-80", "2-2-80"), 
                 EncounterID = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L), Date = c("1-1-21", "1-2-21", "1-3-21", "1-6-21", "1-6-21", "1-6-21"), 
                 Type = c("Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Care", "Out"), 
                 label = c("Check Were you given any info?", "Check Were you given any info?", "Check Were you given any info?", 
                           "Check Were you given any info?", "Check By using this service..", 
                           "Check How satisfied are you?"), 
                 responses = c("(null)", "no", 
                               "yes", "no", "no", "unsat")), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                -6L))
```

I also have the code below that's supposed to help me rename repeated columns but it doesn't. I don't get any error. If you copy paste the code above and below into your editor, it should run.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(UserID, label) %>% 
  mutate(label=if (n() > 1) paste0(label,row_number()) else label)
```

Comment: Your solution works. Assign it to a new dataframe.  `df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(UserID, label) %>%  mutate(label=if (n() > 1) paste0(label,row_number()) else label)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code works. I just had to assign it to a new data frame. Thanks @Bloxx